# Ordering on bar chart

Tags: dc.js

I am looking at ordering the chart like the example below, the background colour is generated from a boolean so, would like to order boolean (true ones in red first), frequency descending.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I guess you've tried [chart.ordering()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#ordering__anchor)?

Comment: it only seems to allow ordering by 1 domain? i.e. the boolean or frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this: through a multivalue ordering, or through a grouped bar chart.

#### Multivalue ordering

Although [chart.ordering()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#ordering__anchor) has to return a single value, you can combine multiple values into a single sort value.

Assuming you've set up your group so the reduced values have fields `bool` and `frequency`, you could produce a single value that sorts by `bool` first and `frequency` second:

```
chart.ordering(function(kv) {
    return - (kv.value.bool * 1000 + kv.value.frequency);
});
```

This assumes that frequency doesn't go above 1000. You could use a bigger multiplier if frequency goes higher than that.

It also uses a trick that boolean value will coerce to 1 or 0 when put into an arithmetic expression.

If your reduced data doesn't have `bool` and `frequency` parts, you could take a look at [How do I reduce multiple values at once?](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-reduce-multiple-values-at-once) in the FAQ. Or update your question with example data and preferably a fiddle or block.

#### Grouped bars

It looks like there are the same number of green bars as red bars in your example, so the experimental grouped bar feature may also be appropriate.

It's [available in a PR](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1043) to draw grouped bars. It works similar to stacked bars: you'd actually separate your data into groups for each part of each color, and then each color would be a bin in each group.

I don't think this feature supports sorting by value within the groups, but I thought it was worth mentioning because of the visual similarity.